# Date displayed in NodeJS is not the same as the date in MySQL, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, date, timezone

my question is fairly simple however I can't seem to figure out an easy way on how to fix it.

I have an application which is separated in three tiers, Angular 2 for the front-end, NodeJS for the back-end and then MySQL for the persistance.

The question I have concerns the database and the back-end.

I have this table in my database where a date is saved in a date format (I know it shouldn't be called timestamp, but that's not the point), and with PHPMyAdmin I can visualize the following lines:

[image: Database lines, notice the day]

Then my NodeJS script communicates with the database and gets the following results:

[image]

As you can see the date has been influenced by some kind of timezone. What I want to know is what is the best solution in order to have the same result in both sides (the correct value is the one you see in the database).

Comment: When selecting CURDATE() and CURTIME() in my Database the time is shown correctly so the problem comes from the backend part

Comment: A JavaScript date can be represented as UTC or the computer's local time, depending on the `Date` methods used to do so. A MySQL time can be stored in UTC or in MySQL's time zone (depending on the column type) and is always displayed in MySQL's time zone.

Comment: You need to show your code, not just the problem.  Voting to close.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution. I don't really understand why it works, but it does. When creating the connection pool, adding dateStrings: 'date' seems to fix the problem.

here's an example:

```
var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'ohmyhairdb',
    debug    :  false,
    dateStrings: 'date'
});
```

Comment: Note that you should be storing your timestamps in MySQL in a timezone agnostic format (i.e. UTC time).

Comment: I agree with you but in this case, this is an application that will be used by only one particular person. If I have to adapt the application for a broader audience I will consider making it a real timestamp

Answer (score -1):

Better use timestamp while saving the date in the db.
Hope it works.

Comment: I'd rather not change the db's structure and the overall logic behind, but thank you for your proposition